# copy a source texture on a target texture, where the source is larger than the target

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using sfml, and I have two textures a source and a target texture, where the source is of larger size than the target. How would I copy a subrectangle of the source texture onto the target texture?

Comment: Do you really want to copy over a texture or maybe you are looking for a solution where you have a large sprite (sheet) and want to reference a different area of the sheet?

Comment: yes, I have too much texture data to store everything at once. This means I sometimes have to recompute it. I am aware that I could download the texture to the CPU (using sf:Image), but I wonder if there is a better way, since all I need to do is copy a part of the source texture onto the target texture

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [`Sprite`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php) along with [`setTexture` and `setTextureRect`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560).
Texture aren't really used for copying parts around.

Or you could use an [`Image`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php) and [`copy`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Image.php#ab2fa337c956f85f93377dcb52153a45a).

Comment: Nope I can't use sprites, since I need to recompute the texture. I wonder if there is a way to carry out the stated operation without going through the cpu (and having to download/upload from the gpu).

Comment: @mnr Why? What exactly are you trying to do?